# How to run a client and self hosted server in the same console app?

Tags: c#, .net, socket.io, signalr

I have a self hosted signalR app in .NET core and I want to run a socketIO client that connects with a completely different socketIO server but when I run the signalR server, the socketIO client is not able to receive commands from the external socketIO server.
I have tried using threads to run the socketIO client buy no luck there. My guess is that when I run the SignalR server with "host.Run()" command mentioned in the code below, it blocks my socketIO client connection somehow.
How can I run a SignalR server (self hosted) and a socketIO client on the same console app so that they don't block each other?
P.S. I am using the 'SocketIOClient' nuget package for creating socketIO client.
My code looks somewhat like this:

'''

```
        string serviceAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SocketIOServerAddress"];

        // Get SignalR hub context
        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
        var hubContext = host.Services.GetService(typeof(IHubContext<MyHub>));

        socketClient = new MySocketIOClient((IHubContext<MyHub>)hubContext, serviceAddress);

        await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => {
            await socketClient.ConnectAsync();
            Console.ReadKey();
        });

        Console.WriteLine("Starting SignalR host...");

        //host.Run();
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { host.Run(); });
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

You could try running either one in a background service: https://blog.computedcloud.com/background-services-in-net-core-console-app/